# Java using Jsoup to get link from html code

Tags: java, jsoup

so i want to store the url of this image

i am searching for this html code:

```
<link rel="image_src" href="http://ex.com/Data/CLOCK/fb.jpg">
```

by

```
Elements el = doc.getElementsByAttribute("rel");
Element link = el.select("image_src").first();
```

the code above gives all the links in the html document which contains around 30+ links. is there a way to get that specific link above?

Thanks

Comment: It's been 5 years, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can start off with a `Document` and work with `CSS` selectors:

```
String selector = "link[rel=image_src][href=http://ex.com/Data/CLOCK/fb.jpg]";
Element theElement = doc.select(selector).first();
```

Comment: the problem is that my code prints all the links in the html doc. I need a way to search for only that link above.

Comment: Sorry. I reviewed the answer.